# How can I Change the encoding of a file 'without BOM' to an 'Windows - 1252' encoded file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, character-encoding, file-conversion

This is my function to convert the encoding of a file.
Before conversion I opened the file in Notepad++, and checked the Encoding using encoding menu, it shows that the Encoding is in UTF 8. I tried to convert the file using following function, but it did not convert to ASCII.
Please have a look into function.

```
public static void ConvertFileEncoding(string srcFile, Encoding srcEncoding, string tempFile)
    {

        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(srcFile))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile, false, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                char[] buf = new char[1024];

                while (true)
                {
                    int count = reader.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    writer.Write(buf, 0, count);
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.Copy(tempFile, srcFile, true); // Source file is replaced with Temp file 
            DeleteTempFile(tempFile);

            // TO DO  -- Log Sucess Details
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new IOException("Encoding conversion failed.", e);

            // TO DO  -- Log failure Details
        }
    }
```

**Please help me on understanding what wrong happenes when I convert the file without BOM to Windows-1252?**

Comment: Which is it that you want, ASCII or Windows-1252? While the encoding of a file is determined by the writer, the output might be identical for numerous encodings. (Don't get confused by your test data being subject to this.) A reader just has to use the encoding the writer used.

Comment: What do you want to happen when your Unicode input data contains characters that are not in your target character set? Choices: replace with '?', throw an exception, or believe it's never going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Characters that have values less than 128 in ASCII are all the same when encoded in UTF-8 or ASCII. If your file consists only of these (it is likely) then the file is identical as UTF-8 or ASCII.

A program can't be expected to distinguish these, because they are identical. UTF-8 is very commonly used now, so it's a reasonable choice when a program has no information other than the content of a file to guess from and it wants to display the encoding.

Comment: My requirement was to import the content of file to an SQL table.
Import will fail if the file is not in windows - 1252 encoding.

Comment: It would be great if these supposed detection algorithms would just say everything that they know: For example, the file is readable as text encoded as UTF-8 w/o BOM, Windows-1252, … and, ASCII (click here for a complete list).